# Node.js: Asynchronous issue when using ImageMagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, imagemagick

I am trying to use imagemagick to resize my images, then passing it off to image compression tools to compress. I am trying to utilize pngquant`

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
// Rename and move original file
if (fs.existsSync(tmpPath + '/' + file)) {
    fs.renameSync(tmpPath + '/' + file, filePath + '/' + fileName);

    // Create new versions of each file
    Object.keys(geddy.config.uploader.imageVersions).forEach(function (version) {
        console.log(version);
        counter += 1;
        var opts = geddy.config.uploader.imageVersions[version];
        console.log(fileName);
        imageMagick.resize({
            width: opts.width,
            srcPath: filePath + '/' + fileName,
            dstPath: filePath + '/' + fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '_' + version + fileType
        }, finish(filePath + '/' + fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '_' + version + fileType));
    });
} else {
    console.log('Unable to find tmp file!');
}
```

Then here is my callback `finish`:

```
finish = function (file) {
    execFile(pngquantPath, ['256', '--force', file], function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
    });
};
```

However, every time `pngquant` it is saying there is no file found. If I take the parameter `file` and go into the shell, run pngquant `file`, it runs the process. So I am assuming it is an asynchronous issue (files not there, it tries to run the process).

This is the error I end up with in the console: 
`{ [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' } ''`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check the file/folder permissions

Comment: I get a `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory` if I try to run `fs.chmodSync(file, '777');` inside the `finish` callback instead of the code listed above

Answer (score 0):

`imageMagick.resize()` expects two arguments: an options object and a callback.

For the second argument, you are not passing `finish` as your callback. Instead, you are *invoking* `finish` and passing whatever `finish` returns (probably `undefined`) as the `callback` argument.

Because you are invoking `finish` at the same time you make the `resize()` call, it is running immediately, before ImageMagick can complete its resize operation.

Try changing the `resize()` line to something like this:

```
imageMagick.resize({
  // (your resize options)
},
function(err) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); } // whatever error handling you need
  var thePath = filePath + '/' + fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '_' +
    version + fileType;
  finish(thePath);
});
```

Now you’re passing a callback function as the second argument, and that function will not be invoked until `imageMagick.resize()` is done. And of course it has the signature of all Node callbacks, which is that the first argument to the callback is `err`. When it’s invoked, the callback does some error-checking and then calls `finish`.

Comment: Hmm, still getting `{ [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' } ''` when trying to run `pngquant` after processing the image. Running `fs.chmodSync(file, '777');` before the `pngquant` command doesn't fix it either... chmodSync is finding the file however (crashed application with my previous code).

Comment: Interesting. I’m not sure `EACCES` means the PNG file is not found. It could mean that it’s unable to spawn the `pngquant` executable for some reason. Are you certain the `pngquantPath` is correct, and is it an absolute path?